# how to stop a tab from becoming muted after obtaining a stream using getDisplayMedia() and prefer CurrentTab:true constraint

Tags: javascript, audio, webrtc

I'm developing a webRTC video chat application with a screen-sharing feature, but after getting the video and audio stream, the tab becomes muted.

```
  const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({
     video: true,
        audio: true,
        preferCurrentTab: true,   //used to locate the current tab easily
      });
   let audio = new Audio("https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-3.mp3");
  audio.play(); // playing audio why this audio is muted
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a known bug from Chromiums side: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1317964&q=preferCurrentTab&can=2

This is the latest update from a Chrome author:

> It is on my schedule to implement suppressLocalAudioPlayback, which would then allow me to make the change you're requesting here. Currently, I plan to implement it in August.

So hopefully in one of the next updates, a fix is shipped.

Answer (score 1):

The [`suppressLocalAudioPlayback`](https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-screen-share/#dfn-suppresslocalaudioplayback) audio constraint [available in Chrome 109](https://developer.chrome.com/en/blog/screen-sharing-improvements-in-chrome-109/) is what you're looking for. When set to true, it indicates that the browser should stop relaying audio to the local speakers when capture starts. The default value for this constraint is false.

```js
// Prompt the user to share a tab, a window or a screen with audio.
// If successful, stop the captured audio from being played out over
// the local device’s speakers.
const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({
  audio: { suppressLocalAudioPlayback: true },
});
const [audioTrack] = stream.getAudioTracks();
const settings = audioTrack.getSettings();
console.log(settings.suppressLocalAudioPlayback); // true
```

As of the time of writing, `suppressLocalAudioPlayback` does not yet work with `applyConstraints()`. See [Chromium Bug 1381959](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1381959).